# Informatica Session - Use Parameter in file name

Tags: session, parameters, informatica

I have a session which reads from a flat file.  This file is named in the submission by whomever submitted it, like this: `load_alfa_data_72578.dat` What I would like to do is have something along these lines `load_alfa_data_$$OPERATOR_ID.dat` where $$OPERATOR_ID is read from the parameter file.

Is this possible? Pictures are worth a thousand words, so here is a screenshot of what is in question.

[image: Session Screenshot]

Comment: I did try that and it didn't work out: Failed to get the initialization properties from the master service process for the prepare phase [Session task instance [DebugInst_s_FAR_ALFA_PREAPPL_CHECK]: Unable to read variable definition from parameter file [/[FilePath]/$Param_FILENAME.parm].] with error code [5179540].

Comment: The parameter file does exist, I am not sure if it is configured on the workflow level, how do I find that out? Thanks!

Comment: Edit the workflow and check the Properties tab.

Comment: Would you be able to paste a screenshot of Workflow Properties tab as well as parameter file content? I think it could help.